# Can a Twilio SMS number be sent via email to one of the big carriers?

Tags: twilio

I have a service that sends me SMS messages, and I'd like to filter them with a Twilio number.  So I have a Twilio phone number now.

However, when I sign up for the service, I have to give my SMS number, AND the "Carrier" which that number is on... and they list the usual suspects, Verizon, AT&T, Sprint, T-Mobile, etc.

I'm guessing they do the "your_phone_number@messaging.sprint.com" or whatever so the service sends email, and then you get a text.

SO: Can I name one of the major carriers for my Twilio number?  If so, which one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible and here is why.

They are not actually sending you an SMS.

They are sending you an email which your phone provider then converts to an SMS and sends to your phone. Twilio does not have a system like that.

Every carrier allows this. For example..

```
        Carrier     Email to SMS Gateway
Alltel  [10-digit phone number]@message.alltel.com
Example: 1234567890@message.alltel.com
AT&T (formerly Cingular)    [10-digit phone number]@txt.att.net
[10-digit phone number]@mms.att.net (MMS)
[10-digit phone number]@cingularme.com
Example: 1234567890@txt.att.net
Boost Mobile    [10-digit phone number]@myboostmobile.com
Example: 1234567890@myboostmobile.com
Nextel (now Sprint Nextel)  [10-digit telephone number]@messaging.nextel.com
Example: 1234567890@messaging.nextel.com
Sprint PCS (now Sprint Nextel)  [10-digit phone number]@messaging.sprintpcs.com
[10-digit phone number]@pm.sprint.com (MMS)
Example: 1234567890@messaging.sprintpcs.com
T-Mobile    [10-digit phone number]@tmomail.net
Example: 1234567890@tmomail.net
US Cellular     [10-digit phone number]email.uscc.net (SMS)
[10-digit phone number]@mms.uscc.net (MMS)
Example: 1234567890@email.uscc.net
Verizon     [10-digit phone number]@vtext.com
[10-digit phone number]@vzwpix.com (MMS)
Example: 1234567890@vtext.com
Virgin Mobile USA   [10-digit phone number]@vmobl.com
Example: 1234567890@vmobl.com
```

What you could do is set up your own so that it converts an email to sms and then sends it to you, then contact whoever you are having send you those messages and have them add your name to the list they support.

Here is even a blog to help you get started

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/05/send-and-receive-sms-messages-via-email-with-twilio-and-sendgrid.html

Comment: Thanks @StevenDStanton -- I was afraid that was the answer.  Easy fix, though!

Comment: Twilio is tight-lipped about how their service works, do you have a source for your claim that they use email gateways? Project Fi, for example, didn't have an email gateway for a long time yet Twilio still worked with it.

Comment: @vaindil please take the time to read the question asked and the answer in full. Neither the question nor the answer address how Twilio sends SMS messages. It only points out that twilio does not have an Email to SMS gateway set up as many cell phone providers do which is why it does not work with systems that send SMS messages via email. Then it links to how to set up your own. At no point does it claim that Twilio uses an email gateway.

Comment: @StevenDStanton I sincerely apologize, I somehow managed to misread both the question and your answer.