# How does a telecom carrier such as AT&T or Verizon send an SMS message to a Twilio number?

Tags: twilio, sms, sms-gateway

I'm trying to further my understanding of how the SMS messaging system or 'texting' works.

Can someone explain how the back-end mechanisms work to deliver an SMS message from someone with an AT&T number to a number owned by Twilio?

This link [Can a Twilio SMS number be sent via email to one of the big carriers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664672/can-a-twilio-sms-number-be-sent-via-email-to-one-of-the-big-carriers) explains how a third-party provider can send "SMS messages" to your phone (via email), but I would like to know more about how the SMS messaging system works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read over this article, provides some insights.

[How One Company You’ve Never Heard Of Swallowed Tens Of Thousands Of Text Messages — Then Spit Them Back Out](https://www.theverge.com/2019/11/21/20974692/valentines-day-text-message-delay-explanation-sms-syniverse-carriers)

> AT&T, T-Mobile, and Sprint currently use Syniverse to route text
> messages to people on other networks, according to data available to
> Tyntec, a smaller messaging services company that spoke with The
> Verge. T-Mobile confirmed that it uses Syniverse, AT&T declined to
> comment, and Sprint did not respond to a request for comment. Verizon
> confirmed that it uses a competitor, SAP.